# Purely analytic proof of the Nielsen-Thurston classification theorem

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

I hope this question is appropriate for the site. I've been looking at the expositions of Bers' proof of the Nielsen-Thurston classification given in Hubbard's *Teichmüller Theory
and Applications to Geometry, Topology, and Dynamics* and in Farb-Margalit's *A primer on mapping class groups*. I was wondering if it's possible to circumvent the use of hyperbolic geometry in the proof.

More precisely, given $S = S_g$, elements are classified according to their translation distance when acting on Teichmueller space $(\mathcal{T}(S), d_{\mathrm{Teich}})$. Here the translation distance of an element is $D(\varphi) = \inf_{\mathcal{X} \in \mathcal{T}(S)} d_\mathrm{Teich}(\mathcal{X}, \varphi \cdot \mathcal{X}) $.

There are three cases:

- If $D(\varphi) = 0$ and the infimum is realized, $\varphi$ is periodic
- If $D(\varphi) >0 $ and the infimum is realized, $\varphi$ is pseudo Anosov.
- If the infimum is not realized, $\varphi$ is reducible.

The first two cases can be handled using only the "analytic" definition of Teichmueller space, as the space of marked Riemann surface structures on $S$. In the first case, you can show that $\varphi$ is (or rather, has a representative that is) conjugate to an isometry of a Riemann surface structure $X$ on $S$, and since $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ is finite, you are done. In the second, you show $\varphi$ is conjugate to a Teichmueller map and hence pseudo Anosov.

But in the third case, Mumford's compactness theorem is used in a crucial way to produce a multicurve that is preserved by $\varphi$. This involves looking at the lengths of closed geodesics with respect to the hyperbolic metric on a Riemann surface, and then controlling how much $\varphi$ can distort these lengths.

So, the questions that I have in mind are (the last two I'm interested in not only because of the proof of this particular theorem, but for their own sake):

1. Is there any other way of producing an invariant multicurve only using Riemann surface structures rather than hyperbolic structures on $S$?
2. Is there some translation for "hyperbolic length of the geodesic representative of the isotopy class of a simple closed curve" to Riemann surface language?
3. Is there an analog of Mumford's compactness theorem (describing some family of compact subsets of moduli space that also give an exhaustion of it) in "analytic" terms?

I'm not hoping for a positive answer to question 1, since I've never seen a complex analysis statement that says anything that would imply "this curve should go exactly here". It (and question 2) might also be a bit misguided, since hyperbolic and Riemann surface structures on a surface are so closely related that it wouldn't make sense to separate them. But maybe there is something that can be done. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the extremal length (which is defined complex-analytically) instead of the hyperbolic length.